# Why does setattr and getattr allow whitespace?

Tags: python, attributes

Let's say I define this class:

```
class A:
    pass

a = A()
```

Now obviously I can set attributes like so:

```
a.x = 5
```

But with `setattr`, I can give `a` attributes which contain whitespace in their names.

```
setattr(a, 'white space', 1)
setattr(a, 'new\nline', None)
```

`dir(a)` contains `'white space'` and `'new\nline'`.

I can't access these attributes using the `.` operator, because it raises a `SyntaxError`:

```
>>> a.white space
  File "<interactive input>", line 1
    a.white space
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> a.new\nline
  File "<interactive input>", line 1
    a.new\nline
              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

But I can with `getattr`:

```
>>> getattr(a, 'white space')
1
>>> getattr(a, 'new\nline')
None
```

Is there a reason behind this functionality? If so, what is it?

Should we make use of this, or conform to the standards defined in PEP8?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Object attributes are merely those attributes defined in an object's `__dict__`.  If you think of it from that perspective then allowing whitespace (or any other character that can be included in a `str`) in an attribute name makes total sense.

```
>>> class X(object):
...  pass
... 
>>> x = X()
>>> setattr(x, 'some attribute', 'foo')
>>> x.__dict__
{'some attribute': 'foo'}
>>> x.__dict__['some attribute']
'foo'
```

That said, Python's language syntax cannot allow for whitespace in direct attribute reference as the interpreter won't know how to property tokenize (parse) the program source.  I'd stick to using [attribute names](http://www.pasteur.fr/formation/infobio/python/ch02s03.html) that can be accessed via direct attribute reference unless you absolutely need to do otherwise.

Comment: It also allows dashes and most other characters not valid as direct attributes.

Comment: Indeed.  The attribute name is just a string that keys a dict.